# How to keep leading zeros when saving string to PostgreSQL using Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Why does Rails strip leading zeros when trying to save a numeric value in Active Record?

For instance:

```
   self.dps_billing_id = "0000060010123363"
   self.save!
```

actually saves `60010123363`.

The column is just a standard string field in a PostgreSQL database:

```
t.string   "dps_billing_id"
```

I need the leading zeros to be stored because my credit-card gateway requires them, but I also cannot simply append a few zeros to the result because the amount can change.

How do I stop Rails trimming the zeros?

Comment: Rails would never trim zeros on a string column. Check your code, may be you forgot to apply a migration, or some callbacks convert string value to integer. Is the value okay before you call `save!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because your `dps_billing_id` is of type integer, not string.

In my Rails console:

```
u = User.first 
u.login_count = '0008'   # but login_count is is defined as type integer
u.save
u.reload
ap u  # :login_count => 8
```

Comment: I had changed if from a integer to a string BUT i had not restarted the server. This seems to have been the problem. Thanks for your help maprihoda.

Comment: I had a similar problem when testing with rspec.  After applying the migration, it still wasn't working.  After scratching my head for a while, I remembers that I need to run `rake db:test:prepare`--it's the test env's equivalent of restarting the server