# Keep leading zeros when saving a string in postgres/active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4 with a Postgres DB and am having a problem where leading zeros are not saved in my zip code column. The datatype for this column is string. When I am in rails console and I update and account's zip code from "7040" to "07040" with a leading zero I am told it is saved. However when I look up the object the zip code is still "7040", not "07040".

I saw this question on SO but the answer suggests restarting your server (which I have done with no change in behavior) and mentions that the problem was in that user's case the datatype of the column used to be an integer. My datatype has always been a string.

[keep leading zeros when saving string in active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374511/keep-leading-zeros-when-saving-string-in-active-record)

You can see in the image below a snapshot of me doing this work in rails console. I get an account. I save the zip with a leading zero. The save appears to work. Then I look up the account by its ID and look for the zip and the trailing "0" does not save:

I have updated my console image here with a save!

[rails console example with save!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CjJK.png)

Also I have these validations on the model:

validates :contact_name, :company_name, :organization_id, :billing_address, :city, :state, :zip, presence: true

validates :account_number, uniqueness: {scope: :organization_id}

Also to get more specific with the problem I have two tests here below. Very strangely TEST A fails while TEST B passes. So it isn't a matter of saving the 0 at the front - somehow I am having a problem with saving a string that was prepended with a '0'. Why would that be? I have a lot of zips to update so I can't manually set them all like TEST B - I need to find a way to save them in the manner of TEST A.

```
it 'TEST A' do
  @a= create(:account, zip: '299')
  new_zip = @a.zip.prepend("0")
  @a.zip = new_zip
  @a.save!
  @a.reload
  @z = Account.find @a.id
  expect(@z.zip).to eq('0299')
end

it 'TEST B' do
  @a= create(:account, zip: '299')
  @a.zip = "0299"
  @a.save!
  @a.reload
  @z = Account.find @a.id
  expect(@z.zip).to eq('0299')
end
```

Comment: Post your code where you are reading the value.

Comment: Console does not show `SQL UPDATE` being called on `save` - may be you have some validations which failed.  Try `save!` to see what errors it throws up.

Comment: @WandMaker - thanks for the comment. I just updated my above rails console image with a call to save! I see it say "Account Exists" and no sql update. I guess I am confused - I don't know what validation is breaking. There is only one account with that account number and organization so it isn't breaking my uniqueness validation. Also I thought that a call to .save would return false if a validation failed.

Comment: @WandMaker - also when I do a.valid? in the rails console in this chain of events it returns true and when I do a.reload it reloads the object and a's zip no longer has the correct leading zero. So before a.reload the zip is "07040" and after it is "7040"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you are being bitten by the fact that `insert` and `prepend` both modify the string in-place:

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > s = "a"
 => "a" 
1.9.3-p194 :002 > s.prepend "b"
 => "ba" 
1.9.3-p194 :003 > s
 => "ba" 
1.9.3-p194 :004 > s.insert 0, "c"
 => "cba" 
1.9.3-p194 :005 > s
 => "cba"
```

When you do that, Rails doesn't know that you've changed the string contents. Even assigning `@a.zip = new_zip` doesn't help, because `@a.zip` and `new_zip` are still the same object, and if rails compares them inside of the `zip=` method, they will appear to be identical. Thus Rails thinks the attribute hasn't changed. That's why in your console session when you say `a.save!` no `UPDATE` is issued. Rails doesn't realize the attribute is dirty.

You can work around this by calling `s.zip_will_change!`. Or do an assignment to a new string like `s.zip = "0#{s.zip}"`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I figured out that the prepend was the problem minutes before you posted this and changed what I did (see my answer above). But this explains something I was very confused about.

Answer (score 0):

You can mask the value on the client and not worry about the database.

```
"%05d" % zip_code.to_i
```

Comment: Thanks @AntarrByrd but some zips need the leading zero and some don't so I don't want to add the 0 when I don't need it and I don't want to write for like state specific zips a certain helper. I would love to figure this out in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough what I found out was that the zip was not saving due to these lines:

new_zip = @a.zip.prepend("0")

@a.zip = new_zip

@a.save!

For some reason the code above with the 'prepend' would not save but the code below does works. So I updated my zips with this and it's working.

@a.zip = ("0" + @a.zip)

@a.save